# Final Year Thesis - TOC offset by 1

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Like most final year reports, an acknowledgements and abstract section is required before the TOC. Adding these sections into the TOC with roman numerals as the page numbers worked fine. However, in the TOC the page number is one more than it should be for all entries.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

%adjust your page margins here
\usepackage[top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in, left=1in,right=0.80in]{geometry} % setting the page alignment with this package
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %for embedding images
\usepackage[%dvips, % commented for pdflatex
bookmarks,  colorlinks=false]{hyperref} %for creating links in the pdf version and other additional pdf attributes, no effect on the printed document
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %for embedding another pdf, remove if not required
\usepackage{float} %used for figure placement with H as a parameter
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pslatex} % for times new roman, old package, but works
\usepackage{array} % for making text bold in table
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\def\figurename{\textbf{Figure }}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

%For the header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Hardware RISC-V Processor Learning Tool and Online SoC Training Platform}} % except the center
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Hardware RISC-V Processor Learning Tool and Online SoC Training Platform}}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%For the header and footer Over

%Page Border
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{project/glossaries}

%GLOBAL SETTINGS OVER, DOCUMENT BEGINS
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\lhead{}
%FROM HERE YOUR PAGES START GETTING ADDED
% includes the cover page
\input{project/cover.tex}
\newpage
% includes the title page
\input{project/title.tex}
\newpage

%TABLE OF CONTENTS AND LIST OF FIGURES ARE AUTOMATICALLY ADDED BY FOLLOWING COMMANDS
%ADD FIGURE OF TABLES IF YOU NEED TO, CHECK DOCUMENTATION
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}

% includes the acknowledgements page
\clearpage
\input{project/acknowledgements.tex} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}%
\newpage

\clearpage
\input{project/abstract.tex} % adds the Research Methodology page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\newpage

%To reset the Header & Footer for TOC and LOF
\clearpage
\tableofcontents % adds Index Page
\newpage

 % adds the glossaries page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Glossary}%
\printglossary
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listfigurename}%
\listoffigures % adds List of Figures
\cleardoublepage

%And reset back the settings we choose for Header and Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} %reset numbering to normal for the main content

\input{project/introduction.tex} % adds the introduction page
\input{project/background.tex} % adds the background page
\input{project/design.tex}
\input{project/learning.tex}
\input{project/health.tex}
\input{project/conclusion.tex} % adds the Scheduling and Planning page
\input{project/ref.tex} % adds the References page

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:
[image: Latex Output]

My understanding is that the TOC is numbering differently to the actual document itself. But I don't understand how to manage the pages correctly.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe remove the `\clearpage` befor the `\pagenumbering{arabic}`?

Comment: Allmost all your `\addcontentsline` command are at the wrong place. They should be at the begin of the input files, not at the end.

Comment: I've removed the \clearpage before the \pagenumbering{arabic} and changed the order of the \addcontentsline but the numbering in the TOC is still the same.

Comment: In the screenshot the List of Figures already has arabic numbering in the TOC. Is that also the case on the page of the LoF itself? It might be possible (although not very likely) that something in the Glossary or the LoF changes the numbering. Does the issue still occur if you remove either one or both from the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my answer might already be quite late for you, but I hope this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem like I did.

What seems to be the problem is that `\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}` squeezes the size of the page down and this creates an issue with the links.
If you also notice, apart from the entries having an offset in numbering, clicking on `Glossary` will also be pointing to `List of Figures` sending you to the next section. In order to fix this issue, this is the solution I came up with that completely eliminates the use of \pgfpagesdeclaredlayout

In order to fix it, I would suggest removing the following code block:

```
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
```

and use the package background and tikz for making your margin instead:

```
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=4pt,]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```